# update mysql row field by 1, when updating other fields at the same time

Tags: mysql

I'm aware you can increase a field value by 1 like this:

```
update database set field1 = field1 + 1
```

But I'm updating several values at once like this:

```
update database
(field1, field2, field3)
VALUES
('109', 'whatever', (field3 + 1))
```

I guess you all see what Im trying to do.
Increase field3 by 1, when i run this update.
 But this code doesnt work. What is the right syntax here?

Comment: update database set field1 = '109', field2 = 'whatever', field3 = field3 + 1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
update 
   database
set
field1 = '109', 
field2 = 'whatever', 
field3 = field3 + 1;
```

Comment: alright, so its not possible by the syntax above? with fields in the first () and values in second () ?

Comment: I haven't ever happen to see such option neither found in the docs: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/update.html . Is that kind of syntax essential for you ?

Comment: i dunno where i got it from, but it works on simple updates with no math :S

Comment: Please find below answer by @auntyellow which more accurately covers your intuition - I've never crossed `REPLACE` statements (more MSSQL user) so I have to learn more :)

Answer (score 0):

In mysql, INSERT and UPDATE have different syntax:

```
INSERT INTO table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)

UPDATE table SET value1 = column1, value2 = column2, ...
```

But for REPLACE, both can work:

```
REPLACE INTO table (column1, column2, ...) VALUES (value1, value2, ...)

REPLACE INTO table SET value1 = column1, value2 = column2, ...
```